# NPE when calling initOwner on Alert (JavaFX)

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I am writing a program that shows an `Alert`, and I'm trying to call `initOwner` so that it will use the application icon, but I'm getting a `NullPointerException`.

Here's a minimal example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class AlertTest extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(final Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        final Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
        alert.initOwner(primaryStage); // line 9
        alert.showAndWait();
    }

    public static void main(final String... args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

and the relevant stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javafx.scene.control.HeavyweightDialog.updateStageBindings(HeavyweightDialog.java:319)
    at javafx.scene.control.HeavyweightDialog.initOwner(HeavyweightDialog.java:120)
    at javafx.scene.control.Dialog.initOwner(Dialog.java:451)
    at AlertTest.start(AlertTest.java:9)
```

What am I doing wrong?

I'm using Oracle's JDK 1.8.0_51 in Linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting a `NullPointerException` because you did not set a `Scene` to the primary stage.

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        final Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new Group(), 300, 300, Color.BLACK));

        alert.initOwner(primaryStage);

        alert.showAndWait();
    }

    public static void main(final String... args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: So I need to set a scene even though I don't use a main application window?

Comment: @aditsu Yes you must specify a Scene.

Comment: Alright, thanks, btw `new Scene(new Group())` seems to be sufficient

Comment: Now the alert position seems to be affected (it goes to the top-left screen corner), but I guess that's a different problem